# Marginal product versus marginal productivity in a Cobb-Douglas production function

Tags: production-function, cobb-douglas

CFA Kaplan Schweser claim that

> Cobb-Douglas function exhibits constant marginal product of capital
>   but diminishing marginal productivity of capital.

I think this statement is not right.
My view is that Cobb-Douglas production functions exhibits decreasing marginal product of capital and constant marginal productivity of capital.

I am more or less sure that Schweser made a mistake but just want to confirm.

Comment: Do you have the link to the quote?

Comment: It's from the book. level 2, book 1, page 298 - kaplan schweser notes for cfa level 2

Comment: Why don't you enhance your question with a few mathematical calculations, after, that is, _defining clearly_ what "marginal productivity" is (contrasted with "marginal product")?

Comment: I think you should write down the books argument and then why you think it is wrong.

Comment: like Alecos, I have no idea what the difference between "marginal product" and "marginal productivity" is supposed to be. Certainly there is not a distinction in conventional usage.